# Win32 C++ effective storage or creation of bitmaps used for colour picker background

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, resources, color-picker

I am writing an HSV colour picker in plain win32 c++.

I have a Sat/Val box and a Hue slider exactly like the image on the left here:

[image]

Up until now I was just generating the background of the Sat-Val box whenever I needed it.

But now that I have a simple prototype and I am circling around to refactor and clean up I have realized that it actually takes a sizeable amount of time to generate the background bitmap for the sat-val box.

Since scrolling the hue slider should update the sat-val box with the appropriate hue, and it should be responsive and fast, I guess I cannot generate the background on the fly because it's too costly.

I have been using a very simple function like this:

```
HBITMAP ColorPicker::genSVBackground(uint32_t hue)
{
  uint32_t width = 256;
  uint32_t height = 256;
  HDC hDC = GetDC(hwnd);
  HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
  HBITMAP bitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, width, height);
  HGDIOBJ oldObj = SelectObject(memDC, bitmap);
  for (uint32_t y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
    for (uint32_t x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
      RGBColor rgbCol = hsv_to_rgb(HSVColor(hue, x, 255 - y));
      COLORREF col = (rgbCol.blue << 16) | (rgbCol.green << 8) | (rgbCol.red);
      SetPixel(memDC, x, y, col);
    }
  }
  SelectObject(memDC, oldObj);
  DeleteDC(memDC);
  return bitmap;
}
```

So the first question is:

Can I make this faster? Fast enough that I can still generate it on the fly? Should I?

And if I cannot make it faster, or if there's really no point and I might as well just use an external resource instead.

What is the best approach to go about storing this in an external resource?

Should I create one giant array that describes a 'cube' of hue x sat x val (my hue, sat and val system is 0-255 each) so I can just load the entire thing into memory and index certain positions to read out an entire background slice?

I know how to do the specifics of the resource storage/loading I'm just not sure if I'm approaching this problem the right way.

Should I store each slice as a separate resource? 256 of them?

Is there a standard way to solving this kind of thing?

Comment: Can you elaborate on thes two things:  What performance do you need (e.g. how fast does it need to be)?  And what performance are you measuring (e.g. how fast is it currently).  And what has benchmarking revealed?

Comment: Try my Direct2D picker also: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5270027/A-modern-Direct2D-color-picker-for-plain-Win32

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis I actually got a lot of inspiration from that :) my tool is actually specialized and just has a 'color picker' window. Thanks for your work I definitely browsed through it during development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the source of your slowness is writing one pixel at a time to the memory DC.

Instead of calling SetPixel 256x256 times in a loop, blast an entire matrix of pixels to the DC at once. At the very least, that's 64K function invocations.

I used to do this kind of buffering with GDI+ all the time.  I'd create a Bitmap object and then call the LockBits method on it.  Do my rendering directly on the returned pointer, and then UnlockBits. It's been a while since I've done the pure Win32 variations of this, but I'm sure it's possible.

Comment: I think that's probably the answer... I didn't quite realize that there was a way to write to the bits beyond SetPixel and the other drawing APIs. Locksbits to get a direct pointer to the buffer sounds like it would speed things up, thanks I will try this but I'm not accepting as answer yet.

Comment: I think what you want to do is invoke [CreateBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createbitmap) with a buffer that you filled with color values.

Comment: A minor perf optimization is to make your `hsv_to_rgb(HSVColor(hue, x, 255 - y));` as inlined as possible. Consider having this be a macro instead of a pair of nested functions. Function call overhead is probably ok for 256x256. But it's a killer on bigger images.

Comment: Yeah there's definitely lots of places I can cut down on performance this was merely a prototype. The performance issues were definitely from SetPixel in the nested loop and using CreateBitmap on a pre-existing array seems to solve it. I can definitely apply some perf analysis and clean up elsewhere though. Going to mark this resolved for now thanks.